# Find all cubic residues $\bmod p$ where $p = 2 \bmod 3$

Tags: number-theory

If $p = 2 \bmod 3$ is there a way to know which $a$ is a cubic residue? i.e for which $a$ the equation $x^3 = a \bmod p$ has an integer solution?

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_reciprocity) says they *all* are, and gives a very simple proof, using Fermat's little theorem - so I guess I'm missing the point of the question.

Answer (score 2):

For $p \equiv 2 \pmod 3$ the cubing map is one to one and everything is a cubic residue

Answer (score 0):

There's a general symbol that works for primes in $\mathbb{Z}[e^{i\pi/3}]$, the Eisenstein integers, defined as $$\left(\frac{\alpha}{\pi}\right)_{3}\equiv \alpha^{(N(\pi)-1)/3}$$ where $\pi$ is an Eisenstein prime not dividing $\alpha\in\mathbb{Z}[e^{i\pi/3}]$. Rational primes $p\equiv 2\pmod{3}$ are also Eisenstein primes.